# To find the number of unique path in a matrix

Tags: c

Given a M X N matrix with your initial position at top-left cell, find the number of possible unique paths to reach the bottom right cell of the matrix from the initial position.
Possible moves can be either down or right at any point in time.

For the input of M=5,N=11. The correct output should be 1001.
The output is different for different IDE.

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int div(int tot,int j,int n,int m)
 {
      int i;
      int fn=1;
      int fd=1;
      int f=1;
      int p;
      for(i=tot;i>=j;i--)
      {
              fn=fn*i;
      }
      for(i=n;i>=1;i--)
      {
              fd=fd*i;
      }
      p=fn/fd;

      for(i=j-1;i>=m+1;i--)
              f=f*i;
              p=p*f;

              return p;


}



int main()
{
              int M,N;
              int unqPath;
              int i,T;
              int j,path;
              int m,n;
              int flag=0;
              scanf("%d",&T);

              for(i=0;i<T;i++)
              {
                      scanf("%d",&M);
                      scanf("%d",&N);

                      if(M>=N)
    {
        path=1;
        for(j=(M-1)+(N-1);j>(M-1);j--)
        {

            path=path*j;
            if(path<=0)
            {

                unqPath=div(((M-1)+(N-1)),j+1,N-1,M-1);
                flag=1;
                printf("\n\n%d",unqPath);
                break;
            }

        }



        if(flag==0)
        {

            n=1;
            for(j=(N-1);j>=1;j--)
            {


                n=n*j;
            }

            unqPath=path/n;
            printf("%d",unqPath);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        path=1;
        for(j=(M-1)+(N-1);j>(N-1);j--)
        {


            path=path*j;
            if(path<=0)
            {
                unqPath=div((M-1)+(N-1),j+1,M-1,N-1);
                flag=1;
                printf("%d",unqPath);
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag==0)
        {


            m=1;
            for(j=(M-1);j>=1;j--)
            {

                m=m*j;
            }
            unqPath=path/m;

            printf("\n%d",unqPath);
        }
    }
}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is an IDE?

Comment: What results are given by which IDE (integrated development environment)?

Comment: Just move diagonally and lie about what the rules are.  That's the way we do things these days.

Comment: @RobertBaron: IDE stands for [Integrated Development Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment).

Comment: @Eric Postpischil I know this is one possible definition. I am asking because I think more details should be given about that!

Comment: @RobertBaron: Then the question to ask is “What specific IDEs are you using, including version?”

Comment: @Eric Postpischil  What if IDE does not mean what you think? It is not defined in the question!

Comment: @RobertBaron: That is absurd. It does not stand for Integrated Drive Electronics. Integrated Development Environment completely suits the context, and alternative meanings do not. Can you propose any that make sense? You might as well question whether the OP is talking about the same C with the C tag as everybody else or they are using another language that has no relationship to common C. Or that they are writing in some language that is not English, so their words have another meaning. In any case, the question “What specific IDEs are you using, including version?” would clear that up.

Comment: @ Eric Postpischil Wow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is too complex. You should first study the way paths are constructed to gain time.

When at a given point x,y, you can go either down or right. So the number of paths from this point is the sum of the number of paths when going down or right.
Special case is when the point is on a border, where there is only one path.

So, you get the following code with a recursive implementation of the computation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// cells are numbered (1..xmax, 1..ymax)
// x an y are position of points
// xmax and ymax are the rectangle size
int nbrpaths(int x, int y, int xmax, int ymax)
{
  if(x==xmax || y==ymax) return 1; // On a south or east border ->
                                   // only one solution: go straight right or down
  return nbrpaths(x+1,y,xmax,ymax)   // go right and find a path 
        + nbrpaths(x,y+1,xmax,ymax); // go down and find a path
}

int main()
{
  int xmax=5, ymax=11, x=1, y=1;
  int nbr=nbrpaths(x,y,xmax,ymax);
  printf("number of paths: %d\n",nbr);
}
// prints: number of paths: 1001
```

Answer (score 1):

If the matrix is n x m, then the number of unique paths is (n+m-2)!/((n-1)!(m-1)!). You could simply code that formula.

See [Combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at it like this:

When you are in the upper left corner and move down, you get a new matrix with 1 less row and same number of columns.

When you are in the upper left corner and move 1 rigth and then down, you get a new matrix with 1 less row and 1 less column.

When you are in the upper left corner and move 2 rigth and then down, you get a new matrix with 1 less row and 2 less columns.

and so on.

So to calculate the result for a (R, C) matrix, you can calculate it as a sum of the result from a number of smaller matrices. Like:

```
count(R, C) = count(R-1, C-0) + count(R-1, C-1) + count(R-1, C-2) + ... + count(R-1, 1)
```

This can be handled by recursion. Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count(int r, int c)
{
  if (r == 1) return 1;
  if (c == 1) return 1;
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i=0; i < c; ++i)
  {
      sum += count(r-1, c-i);
  }

  return sum;
}

int main()
{
  int r=5, c=11;
  int res=count(r,c);
  printf("Result: %d\n", res);
}
```